# Can i add 2 Function on single button(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Morning, I have a question can I add 2 functions on a `single button Like On/Off button` but just 1 button, when I click once to turn `off` then I click that button again turn `on`

```
 public void DrawingOn()
{
    onScreenDrawing.enabled = true;
}
public void DrawingOff()
{
    onScreenDrawing.enabled = false;
}
```

I try to add all of them on onClick button but that always turn off even though I clicked once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Design view from your IDE, add or change the Click handler of your button to:

```
void Click_Button()
{
    onScreenDrawing.enabled = !onScreenDrawing.enabled;
}
```

Comment: This would be  my version too

Answer (score 0):

You just need one event to do that.
Change your code to something like this

```
   public void ChangeState() {
    bool updated;
    if(onScreenDrawing.enabled){
        onScreenDrawing.enabled = false;
        updated = true
     }else{
      if(updated == false){
         onScreenDrawing.enabled = true;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you assigned the function to the button on the inspector ?
Try with the updated code

Comment: Use `onScreenDrawing.enabled = !onScreenDrawing.enabled` instead of all that code.

Comment: you seem to have a good idea... show us the complete solution